# SSHにてAWSにあるインスタンスにログインしたい

Tags: aws, ssh

Amazon Web Service にてインスタンスを作成しキーペアをダウンロードディレクトリに落としました。

EC2へのsshログインしたく

`ssh -i my-keypair.pem ec2-user@**** (EIPアドレス)` を実行したところ

```
Warning: Identity file aws_keypair.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

となりそこから先に行くために全く知識なく関連するWebサイトなどを徘徊しております。

環境はMacbook air (El Capitan)

ターミナルでプログラムのための環境操作したりするといったレベルの概念しかありません。

ポートが関係しているのか、概念もままならずに相談して解決できたらなと考え投稿させていただきました。

ご教唆よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

秘密鍵のファイルが指定した場所に置かれていないようです。

`my-keypair.pem`を秘密鍵のファイルへの**フルパス**に書き換えて実行してみてください。

以下は、ダウンロードディレクトリに my-keypair.pem がある場合の例です。

```
ssh -i ~/Downloads/my-keypair.pem ec2-user@****
```

Answer (score 1):

秘密鍵の権限を600にする事もお忘れなく。