# AWS EC2 のインスタンスからコピーして作成したインスタンスのファイルを更新したい

Tags: aws, amazon-ec2

AWS EC2について質問があるので投稿させていただきます。
やりたいこととしては、あるWordpressサイトの類似サイトを作成することです。

EC2のインスタンスA(大元となるWordpressサイトのWebページ)、インスタンスB(大元となるWordpressサイトのDB)から生み出したそれぞれのAMIを元に、
新しくインスタンスC(類似したWordpressサイトのWebページ)、インスタンスD(類似したWordpressサイトのDB)を作成しました。

インスタンスCに含まれているconfig.phpをローカルにダウンロードし、そのファイルを編集することで、連携するDBをインスタンスBからインスタンスDに変更したのちに、インスタンスDを編集して類似サイトを作っていきたいですが
config.phpをローカルにダウンロードすることができないです。

私自身は大元となるサイトの制作に携わっていないため、インスタンスA、インスタンスBに関する
ファイルは保持していません。

どうしたらconfig.phpをローカルにダウンロードできますか？
手順としては、以下の操作を行っております。

◎行った手順
インスタンス（リモート）から該当ファイルをローカルにコピー→Atom（エディタ）でFTP接続できるプラグインを使用し、ローカルとインスタンスを連携→ローカルでファイルを編集し、保存すればそれがインスタンスに反映されることから、インスタンスにログインし、該当ファイルをローカルにダウンロードする。

① `ssh (ユーザ名)@(パブリックIP) -i (秘密鍵ファイルのフルパス) -p (ポート番号)`もしくは`ssh -i (秘密鍵ファイルのフルパス)@(パブリックDNS)`でインスタンス接続（ついでに`sudo yum update`でインスタンス更新）

② `pwd`で現在いるディレクトリを確認、`ls -a`でディレクトリ直下にあるフォルダ確認→`cd wordpress`でWordpressのフォルダに移動

③ ②と同じ流れでwordpressファイルの中の`wp-config.php`ファイルを確認、`scp -i (秘密鍵のフルパス) (ユーザ名)@(パブリックIP):(目的のファイルがある場所) (ダウンロードするローカルの場所)`でダウンロードを試みる

```
Warning: Identity file /home/ec2-user/Desktop/********.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

というエラーメッセージが出てダウンロードできず。

パブリックキーの権限が問題かと考え、`chmod 0600 /Users/[ローカルのユーザ名]/Desktop/********.pem`というコマンドを打つが、

```
chmod: `/Users/[ローカルのユーザ名]/Desktop/********.pem' にアクセスできません: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません
```

というメッセージが出る。

そこで、パブリックキーのフルパスが間違っているのが問題かと思い、`scp -i ~/desktop/********.pem ec2-user@[パブリックIP]:/home/ec2-user/wordpress ~/desktop`というコマンドを打つが、やはり

```
Warning: Identity file /home/ec2-user/desktop/********.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

という表示がされ、通らない。

初心者ですが、諸先輩方、お力添えお願いいたします。

Comment: 重複候補(回答あり) - [SSHにてAWSにあるインスタンスにログインしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/23073/3060)

Comment: まずはコマンド実行時に指定したファイル (特に***.pem) が存在するのかをよく確認してみてください。質問にも `(ほにゃらら)` の形式で伏せ字にしてしまうのではなく、**実際に実行したコマンドやパス** を載せたほうがよいかと思います。

Comment: chmodでファイルが見つからないので、まずそこを解決すべきだと思います。findでpemのディレクトリを再度確認してchmodを通すべきでかと思います。