# バッチファイルからのSSH接続でエラー: Identity file key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory

Tags: ssh, batch-file

将棋ソフトの探索エンジンをAWS上に置こうと考えています。

手順としては以下を参考にしました。
https://www.mikunimaru.com/entry/ShogiAWS

手順を追い、インスタンスが動いているところまでは記述どおりに確認できました。

しかし、バッチファイルの動作確認の場所で想定どおりの動きをしません。

実行しようとしているバッチファイル

```
@echo off
setlocal
cd /d %~dp0
ssh -i key.pem ec2-user@■■■■ cd ./engine;./YaneuraOu-AVX2
pause
```

手順通りに
「■■■■」を作成したインスタンスのパブリックDNSに書き換え、秘密鍵は「key.pem」という名前でバッチファイルと同じフォルダに置き、実行しました。

すると、

```
Warning: Identity file key.pem not accessible: No such file or directory.
```

上記ワーニングが出ます。（ワーニング以外は手順に載っている内容と一致していました。）

過去の同様な質問の回答にあるように、sshコマンド以下に秘密鍵ファイルのフルパスを記述するように書き換えてみたのですが、状況は変わりませんでした。
（↓過去の質問）
[SSHにてAWSにあるインスタンスにログインしたい](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23073/ssh%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A6aws%E3%81%AB%E3%81%82%E3%82%8B%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%81%AB%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B0%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E3%81%84)

知識がなく、根本的な原因もわからず、解決できていません。

よろしければご回答お願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

そのファイルがない、といってます。
ファイルパスがあってるかをよくチェックしましょう
そして、バッチファイルで実行ではなく、コマンドプロンプトからsshコマンドを実行してみてください。